# C# Is there a way to resolve lambda expression`s delegate type in code

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, reflection

My goal is to support sorting in an application and expose it via REST API that would accept the parameter as a string.

Current implementation is along the lines of this:

```
GetUsers (Expression<Func<User, int>> sortExpression) {
 // Retrieve users ... 
 return users.orderBy(sortExpression);
}

Usage example:
var users = GetUsers(u => u.Id);
```

the `Expression<Func<User, int>> sortExpression` is widely used in our repository and changing it would be difficult.

What I'd like to do is to be able to swap the `u => u.Id` with something that is generated during run-time.

Something that I have so far is:

```
// sortBy is retrieved from the calling method.
var type = typeof(User).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == sortBy).GetType();

var sortExpression = Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(User)), sortBy);

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));

var expressionBody = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<User, int>), sortExpression, parameter);

var users = GetUsers(expressionBody)
```

I can see at run-time that this does create an expression that fits my needs, but the error is `Argument 5: cannot convert from 'LambdaExpression' to 'Expression<System.Func<User, int>>'` even though the body of the expression is supposed to be set by `typeof(Func<User, int>)`

Comment: You just need to cast the `LambdaExpression` to a `Expression<Func<User, int>>`, for example: `var expressionBody = (Expression<Func<User, int>>)Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<User, int>), sortExpression, parameter);`

Comment: Thank you. 
I've also totally missed that there's a generic way to create the expression using 
```Expression.Lambda<Func<User, int>>(sortExpression, parameter);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what I've been doing wrong.

First: Create the expression body using generic method

```
// Generic Method, return type Expression<Func<User, int>>
Expression.Lambda<Func<User, int>>(sortExpression, parameter);
```

Instead of passing the `typeof(Func<User, int>)` parameter.

```
// Non-generic. Return type LambdaExpression
Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<User, int>), sortExpression, parameter);
```

Second:

I wasn't binding the parameter properly, which made it so that the expression was accessing property of a discarded parameter that wasn't provided to the expression.

```
// I'm creating an expression to access the property of a newly created parameter.
var sortExpression = Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(User)), sortBy);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));
var expressionBody = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, int>>(sortExpression, parameter);

//Above causes an unbinded variable exception since there are two parameters, one of which is not passed/bound.

//Should be:
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));
var sortExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, sortBy);
```